# How to match multiple strings in one column with multiple strings in another column remove matches in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse

Here is my code:

```
A <- c("ruler measure", "measure rulers", "rulers")
B <- c("you can measure things with rulers", "you can measure things with rulers", "you can measure things with rulers")
df <- data.frame(as.character(A), as.character(B))

df_new <- df %>%
  mutate(
    new_B = str_replace_all(B, A, "")
  )
```

What I want is for the columns to look like this:

```
A                          B   
ruler measure             you can things with
measure rulers            you can things with
rulers                    you can measures things with
```

But, str_replace_all() only seems to replace one match of A and B (e.g., ruler), but not another match (e.g., measure)

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Some values are not matching `ruler` vs. `rulers`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a base R solution

```
df <- within(df,
             new_B <- mapply(gsub, 
                             sapply(strsplit(as.character(A),"\\s+"),
                                    function(v) paste0(paste0("\\s+?",v,".*?\\b"),collapse = "|")),
                             "",
                             B))
```

such that

```
> df
               A                                   B                       new_B
1  ruler measure  you can measure things with rulers         you can things with
2 measure rulers you can measures things with rulers         you can things with
3         rulers  you can measure things with rulers you can measure things with
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for any repeated matches, even when I threw some long phrases at it!  You are awesome.

Answer (score 0):

We can replace the space with `|`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
   mutate(new_B = str_replace_all(B, str_replace(A, " ", "|"), ''))
```

Comment: Thanks!  This also worked well, but when I tried it with some new data, it didn't catch all string matches, particularly in longer phrases.  I may not have described my issue perfectly.  I appreciate you trying it in tidyverse.

Comment: @DJ_CBSC iissue is that once you show some code, it becomes necessary to assume that you are trying to replace between corresponding elements of 'A', and 'B'